# Excel FILTER with sorting, discontiguous columns and n-top values in single step

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have attached a screenshot of the original table and the desired result.

What I want is basically to return records from an excel table based on a single criterion (CustomerID), sort the results on another criterion (Date), attach discontiguous columns from an original table, and return only n-rows from that filtered selection (in this case last 3)?

Is there a way to do it in a single step without the use of helper formulas or helper tables including RANK, LARGE, and so on?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is your Excel Version ? Also what if one of customer have only one invoice, what should be the return

Comment: Excel 365, if one customer has one invoice it would only return that invoice. The point is that if customer has 20 invoices to return the last 3.

Comment: try this `=CHOOSECOLS(SORT(TAKE(FILTER(Table1,K2=Table1[Customer ID]),-3),4,-1),1,4,6,7)` where `K2` is `Customer ID` let me know if that works. Note that you should your output as in a table, in Table Structure array formulas dont work. You dont need also in MS365 as the formulas will spill

Comment: Partially, it does filter only 3 last records based on date, but it does not sort them and it has all the columns instead of only those 4 in yellow table.

Comment: please check I have updated the formula. `=CHOOSECOLS(SORT(TAKE(FILTER(Table1,K2=Table1[Customer ID]),-3),4,-1),1,4,6,7)`

Comment: Thanks, works just as expected, like a charm. If I was aware of the EXISTENCE of TAKE and CHOOSECOLS it would have been a trivial problem. Filtering by one customer, TAKEing last n, SORTing it on some column and then, CHOOSEingCOLumns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted, the solution as an answer as it worked for OP

[image]

---

You could try something like this as shown in screenshot below,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `J3`

```
=LET(_table,Table1[#All],
_headers,TAKE(_table,1),
_customerwise,FILTER(DROP(_table,1),DROP(INDEX(_table,,1),1)=K2,""),
_lastthree,TAKE(_customerwise,-3),
_requiredcols,CHOOSECOLS(_lastthree,1,4,6,7),
VSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(_headers,1,4,6,7),SORT(_requiredcols,2,-1)))
```

---

Edit, the one which was posted in comments.

[image]

• Formula in cell `J9`

```
=CHOOSECOLS(SORT(TAKE(FILTER(Table1,K2=Table1[Customer ID]),-3),4,-1),1,4,6,7)
```

---

Literally, the formulas given can be converted to a `LAMBDA()` to create a custom, reusable formula with a friendly name.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `J3`

```
=LISTDATA(Table1[#All],K2)
```

---

Where `LISTDATA()` is a custom and reusable formula with a friendly name, defined in name manager, using `LAMBDA()`

```
=LAMBDA(array,criteria,
LET(_table,array,
_headers,TAKE(_table,1),
_customerwise,FILTER(DROP(_table,1),DROP(INDEX(_table,,1),1)=criteria,""),
_lastthree,TAKE(_customerwise,-3),
_requiredcols,CHOOSECOLS(_lastthree,1,4,6,7),
VSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(_headers,1,4,6,7),SORT(_requiredcols,2,-1))))(B3:H12,K2)
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Takes only array and criteria to give you required output.

<kbd>=LISTDATA(array,crietria)</kbd>

---

Comment: I accepted your answer for the reasons you listed and you were the first on it, although I do not understand the LET solution. I find the one in comments much more elegant and understandable.

Comment: @rioZg if you follow, you will see `LET()` makes it easier and more readable, using the variables. If you follow, and its more elegant, it takes all the pieces one by one and does the operation

Comment: LET and DROP are the next two formulas that I never used, so I will give them a look. Thanks, the solution was achieved!

Comment: @rioZg Yes I could have given in one line, but I broke each part so it makes easier to understand, and way dynamic than any other, it brings the headers as well.

Answer (score 2):

Following your conditions, you can use the following under O365 in `J2` the following formula:

```
=LET(input, TB_Inv, customerId, I2, customers, TB_Inv[Customer],
  TAKE(CHOOSECOLS(SORT(FILTER(TB_Inv, customers=customerId),4,-1),1,4,6,7),3)
)
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample output file]

It sorts by date in descending order, then it takes the first three rows from the final output.

If you want to include the header, then:

```
=LET(input, TB_Inv, customerId, I2, customers, TB_Inv[Customer],
  result, TAKE(CHOOSECOLS(SORT(FILTER(TB_Inv, 
    customers=customerId),4,-1),1,4,6,7),3),
  VSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(TB_Inv[#Headers],1,4,6,7), result)
)
```